# How do I get a JSON object to continuously update The location on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I can't get my map to update The Location Continuously. The Json object doesn't move across the map over time. I have no errors. 
Does JSON work with google maps? 
 A while loop seems useless. It feels simple but I'm not sure how to do it. I couldn't find anything on this on site.

Let me Know what you see.
By the way I'm tracking a moving satellite.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera



}

class Retrievedata extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {



                jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");

                String lat = "latitude : " + jobj.getString("latitude");
                String longit ="longitude : " + jobj.getString("longitude");
                Double latt = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                Double longitt = Double.parseDouble(longit);

                // this will cause onProgressUpdate to be called with lat & long
                 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latt, longitt);
                publishProgress(lat,longit);



                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

                // it's okay to sleep within the background thread



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("RetrieveData", "parse error", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


    }

}
```

}

this is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.celest.iss.whereistheiss"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',   {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: Edit No error. However marker isn't moving

Comment: Json and Google maps are completely separate. Yes, they can work together. Besides that, you never executed that AsyncTask

Comment: What? how do you get it to start a moving marker

Comment: I keep tampering with it I might have ruined it.

Comment: I've never used Google maps, can't help you there, but your AsyncTask should return your coordinate from doInBackground, then update the UI from onPostExecute

Comment: Use a handler with a delay and use the function setPosition for the markers to update the markers. something like: final Runnable updateTask=new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateLocations();
                handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
            }
        };
       handler.postDelayed(updateTask, 2000);
    }